# How to design application messaging service from one user to many users in game

Tags: android, networking, client-server, instant-messaging

I'm making an application for Android that allows me to send a set of geolocation points from one user to a group of users playing a game together, but I don't really know where to start on sending the messages.

I had one idea that involved sending the message from the one user to a server, and then having the server push the message to the other users, but I don't know how to let the server know which users to send the message to.

Am I on the right track? Are there services already set up that deal with this kind of problem? Do you have any other suggestions? Your comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to create a shared context e.g. topic on the server for each group of users.  Sender publishes to the topic.  Listeners are subscribed to the topic.  It is a simple matter of the server receiving a message; mapping to the topic; and sending the message to the subscribers of that topic.

Main design issue is to determine if you need static or dynamic topics.  In other words, in static topics, the server is given a (static) list of topics (via say a config file).  In dynamic variant, you would need to provide the mechanism for dynamic group formation.

Second issue is topic durability.  Can users of the group drop out (of net) and then re-establish connection and get messages that they missed when disconnected? etc.

p.s. there are a variety of messaging frameworks, from JMS to AMPQ to PubSubHub for Java so you can probably highly leverage existing code.  But it really can be something as simple as pushing messages to server via REST calls.  Receivers would need to either poll the server (via an analog REST call) or maintain a connection for the server to push to them.  (The latter is probably not a very good idea if you expect a lot of users.)

[final edit: If you are going to roll your own, I strongly suggest you take a look at Redis.  It should be easy for you to quickly prototype something that way.]

Comment: And there is always P2P as well, sans server.